# Can't find how to change Xbmc mouse speed

Tags: mouse, xbmc

How can I change in Xbmc mouse speed?
In Ubuntu is fine but when I start Xbmc it gets really much too fast...

Comment: this version uses system settings for keyboard and mouse: https://launchpad.net/~wsnipex/+archive/xbmc-fernetmenta-master it has already dropped sdl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting in xbmc to change the mouse speed. Changing the speed would require changing the code for xbmc.

I checked both the settings panels and all the xml settings files in the user data folder.

Answer (score 0):

Change Setting > System> Video Output" from "Full screen" to "Windowed" . Not perfect, but the mouse should be more easier to control now.